# Object not visible in Render Blender 2.8

Tags: rendering

worked for some time on modeling shoe laces and as I rendered the image the laces are not being rendered in blender 2.8

In blender 2.78 it does render all the objects.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: You might have disabled it for the render (camera icon in the outliner)?

Comment: Was this imported from a version of Blender 2.78?

Comment: It was created with Blender 2.79 and imported to Blender 2.80, rendering in Cycles. blender 2.79 does render it and 2.80 does not.